# AWS E2 root access and git

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Rails application at amazon E2 instance.
Server engineer grant me an access to user which is not root.

How can I get root access form console if I have full access to amazon aws account?

I want to run `sudo` commands and install git to syncronize with my local folder and continue with developing app

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get root access without the ability to sudo. Is your instance an ubuntu? If things were configured right, you won't have root access unless someone gives it to you - or you create your own instance. You can try and peak around /home/unbuntu see if you have access to the folder and if a ssh private key file copy was forgotten there. SSH public keys are kept in /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys but only the owner is supposed to have access to them. Misconfigured permissions result in the OS refusing the key - and access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  Generally speaking, you don't get root access.

You need to ask your server engineer to add your user to the sudoers list and make sure passwords are not required.  He should be able to do this by

- ssh-ing into the machine
- calling the command `sudo visudo`
- adding this to the bottom of the file `[YOUR USERNAME HERE]ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

I'm assuming you need this to install packages and what not so the server engineering should be doing this by default.

Answer (score 1):

Once you logged in your ec2 instance as an ec2-user.

You can switch ec2-user to root user. By calling command **sudo su**